# Retrieving specific ID once

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `users` and has a `user_id`, and a table named `groups` and has a `group_id` and also have `user_id` that `is a foreign key` reference from `users's` `user_id`.The situation is here: if the user joined a group, his/her user_id is inserted into table groups. So if the user joined two different groups, the column 'user_id' in table 'groups' will insert two or more same user_id's. Well, I just want to bring the user_id once, either he/she joined two or more groups..

I have no idea how to loop it properly without getting user_id that is the same.... I just want it to loop once...

```
$query_groups = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM groups");
while ($rows_g = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_groups)) {
    $g_user_id = $rows_g['user_id'];
    $query_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$g_user_id'");

    while ($rows_u = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_users)) {
        echo $rows_u['user_id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Er why double the loop? LEFT JOIN is your friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code as follows:

```
$query_groups = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM groups LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = groups.user_id GROUP BY groups.user_id");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_groups))
{
           echo $rows['user_id'];

}
```

Comment: sir I got this error while running this code.... here's the error Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\once.php on line 6

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$rows_g` but the variable is namend `$rows` in the first while loop.

Wrong:

```
$g_user_id = $rows_g['user_id'];
```

Correct:

```
$g_user_id = $rows['user_id'];
```

But try to use joining tables, because this is an inefficient way to get the wanted data.
In your case you should use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I try to use the code of Mr. virmaior, but I got this error: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\once.php on line 5


But whenever I remove the Line 'GROUP BY groups.user_id' it works but its looping the same user_id.

Comment: Well how does your full query look like?